# wordpress Gravity form data save to csv file on submit

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity form plugin on my WordPress website for client registration. Currently I am getting notification on email. I want to save the field data to csv/text file after hitting submit. Please someone suggest me how to do that.
Thanks :)

Comment: Please show your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has a hook `gform_after_submission` which executes after form submitted. You can add your own action where you will get all the form data and then you can create csv/text file there. Here is the documentation.
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/

Answer (score -1):

There has a hook `gform_after_submission` which executes after form submitted as You can add your own action/function where you will get all the form data and then you can create csv/text file there. Here is the documentation. https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/